# How to add my app to iPhone's Search Screen?

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to add my app to the iPhone's search screen? I mean, when the user types some search terms on the search screen, is it possible that my app appears on the list so the user can select it and search there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currenly there's no public Spotlight API in iOS (it is available to Apple apps only). Such an API exists on the Mac, hopefully we'll see it on iOS soon too.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to add items from your app to the iPhone search screen.  The user can find your app if they enter a search string found in the title of your app (e.g. "foo", if your app is called "MyFoo"), but the iPhone search screen won't search your app's documents.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly...
Your app should be showing as a result if you start typing in your app name. 
As long as its installed on the phone. Make sure to include your icons for that screen in the bundle.

small-icon@2x.png  58x58 pixels 
small-icon.png     29x29 pixels